# How can I solve for P in the integer equation: $d = \frac{mNP+1}{B}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I solve for P in the equation: $d = \frac{mNP+1}{B}$, where $P$ is the smallest integer $> 0$ such that $d$ is an integer?

$m, N$ and $B$ are positive integers.  They are usually quite small ($m$ is usually $3$ and the others $< 10$), so it is easy to just do a search but this is inelegant and doesn't work very well in a spreadsheet.

I fiddled with modulo algebra for a while but couldn't come up with a closed form.  This is used in designing fractional-slot windings for motors and generators.

Comment: Oh, and there may not be a valid value for P if you pick the wrong mN and B, so what are the criteria?

Comment: Actually, that's easy: mN and B have to be relatively prime.

Comment: To solve this for tht immediate problem, I just made a table of P vs. mN and B for reasonable numbers.  You get some odd sequences: for B = 17 the sequence of P for increasing mN is 16 8 11 4 10 14 12 2 15 5 3 7 13 6 9 1 0, [repeat], where the 0 is a placeholder for "no solution >0".

Answer (score 0):

The equation may be written as
                                (Bd-1)/3N = p (say m=3)
 if you allow B=7,then.         (7d-1)/3N = p
This will have solution for d=1 & N=2 » p=1
                            d=4 & N=3 » p=3
                            d=7 & N=4 » p=4
                            d=13& N=5 » p=6
                            d=13& N=6 » p=5
       allow B=5            d=5 & N=2 » p=4
                            d=5 & N=4 » p=2
                            d=5 & N=8 » p=1
the max value of d shall be designed to enumerate more integers for p.

Comment: I can do that too (see above), but it doesn't give me a formula I can put in a spreadsheet.